# Pandas chain indexing - replacing key column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I try the following things on a dataframe:

1. filter column `Topic` with the value '*job*'
2. for those rows, check if `content` has the string '*bb*'
3. rename `Topic` values of resulting selection to '*civ*'

Below is a sample dataframe

```
{'topic': {0: 'job', 1: 'job', 2: 'job', 3: 'edu', 4: 'edu', 5: 'edu'},
 'content': {0: 'a b cc',
  1: 'a bb c',
  2: 'aa bb c',
  3: 'ee dd uu',
  4: 'bb e d u',
  5: 'e dd uu'}}
```

The resulting dataframe should look like this

```
  topic | content
0   job | a b cc
1   civ | a bb c
2   civ | aa bb c
3   edu | ee dd uu
4   edu | bb e d u
5   edu | e dd uu
```

I tried the floowing approach. But nothing happens.

```
df[df['topic']=='job'][df.content.str.contains("bb")==True]["topic"]='game'
```

I also tried using a mask shown in the following [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy). But i get the error at the step `df.loc[mask,'topic']` saying "*ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key*"

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with chain masks by `&` for bitwise `and`:

```
df.loc[(df['topic']=='job') & df.content.str.contains("bb"), "topic"]='game'
print (df)
  topic   content
0   job    a b cc
1  game    a bb c
2  game   aa bb c
3   edu  ee dd uu
4   edu  bb e d u
5   edu   e dd uu
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `df.loc` with `eq` and `str.contains`:

```
df.loc[df['topic'].eq('job') & df['content'].str.contains('bb'), 'topic'] = 'game'
```